# Prove a sequence to the power n converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Here is my question:

Let $a \in \Re$ such that $|a|\lt 1$ and  $\{a_n\}$ a sequence. Prove that if $a_n \to a$, then $a_n^n \to 0$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since $\dfrac{\lvert a\rvert+1}2>\lvert a\rvert$, eventually $\lvert a_n\rvert<\dfrac{\lvert a\rvert+1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Put $\;1-|a|=\epsilon>0\;$ , then there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. for $\;n>N\;$ we have

$$|a_n|<|a|+\frac\epsilon2\implies |a_n|^n\le\left(|a|+\frac\epsilon2\right)^n$$

Comment: Im sorry Im not able to complete the proof

Comment: @Fadmad $$\left(|a|+\frac\epsilon2\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;\;\text{since}\;\;0<|a|+\frac\epsilon2<1\;\ldots$$and now just apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I see, but why set 1-a=E, it implies that E is less then 1, but E can also be greater than 1.

Comment: Also, E/2 could be a large number therefore it would go to infinity, we cant just make E dependable on a

Comment: @Fadmad If we put $\;1-|a|=\epsilon\;$ and **we know that** $\;|a|<1\;$ , how can $\;\epsilon>0\;$ be a greater than $\;1\;$ ?? This is **exactly** the point !